# Hibernate: Left Join with Join Table and Join Restriction

Tags: hibernate, join

I want this SQL:

```
select * from tableA
left outer join joinAB on tableA.id = joinAB.a_id
left outer join tableB on tableB.id = joinAB.b_id and tableB.otherCol = 4;
```

With a model like this:

```
class TableA {
    @OneToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "joinAB",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "a_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "b_id")
    )
    private Set<TableB> bs;
}
```

I'm trying to write a Criteria that will return all of the TableAs with their bs, but also include the as without any bs. Hence the left outer join. tableB is large, so otherCol is actually an indexed column that I need to restrict to keep MySQL from doing a full table scan.

I'm using this criteria:

```
this.getSession().createCriteria(TableA.class)
    .createAlias("bs", "bs", CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN,                       
    Restrictions.eq("bs.otherCol", 4));
```

But I end up with this SQL:

```
select * from tableA this_ left outer join joinAB bs5_ 
on this_.id=bs5_.a_id and ( bs1_.otherCol=4 ) 
left outer join tableB bs1_ on bs5_.b_id=bs1_.id and ( bs1_.otherCol=4 )
```

So you see it's adding a nonsensical restriction on the join table (the resulting SQL wont even execute.)

How do I get it to do the right thing?

Comment: After several attempts, I doubt that's possible with plain hibernate since you're trying to force it to declare `bs` empty even if there *are* associations, creating a disconnect between database and ORM representation. Love to be proven wrong, though.

Comment: I've never tried it, but from the manual a [@Filter](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/manual/en-US/html_single/#d5e8634) *may* help you?

Answer (score 1):

```java
Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(TableA.class);        

crit.createCriteria("joinAB", "AB", JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN);
crit.createCriteria("tableB", "TB", JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN, 

Restrictions.eq("TB.otherCol", "4"));
crit.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
```